# How to access items on a JMenu and work with Action Listener?

Tags: java, swing

I ran into an issue with my java code where the action listener is not working. I am supposed to create a GUI that has a menu bar that performs some actions when those buttons are clicked. For example, if the user selects an option on the "Meals" menu and an option on the "Dorms" menu, it should calculate the values that each of those items has assigned and then outputted to the total cost JField.

[image]

[image]

This is what my code looks like

```
private class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

//The user has chosen a new dorm or new meal plan
//Get the choices from the dormBox and mealBox and recalculate charges
//Display the new charges in the totalField

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    //Get the choices from the dormBox and mealBox
    int totalCost;
    int dormIndex = menu.getComponentCount();
    int dormCost=dormCosts[dormIndex];
    int mealIndex=dorm.getComponentCount();
    int mealCost=mealCosts[mealIndex];
    //Calculate the charges
    totalCost=dormCost+mealCost;

    //Display the new charges 
    totalField.setText("$"+Integer.toString(totalCost));
  }
}
```

How should I get it working well..?

Comment: Did you register the action listener with your menu item instance? Something like:  yourMenuItem.addActionListener(yourMenuActionListenerInstance);

Comment: Did you add the `MenuActionListener` to the relevant GUI elements?

Comment: I did something like this:
menu.addActionListener(choiceListener);
dorm.addActionListener(choiceListener);

Comment: `getComponentCount()` returns, as the method name suggests, the number of components added to the menu. What makes you think, that this has anything to do with the index of the clicked menu? In fact, when you have *n* elements and *n* corresponding menu items, the returned count is expected to be *n*, which is always an invalid index for the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t write listeners which try to guess about the right values to use. When you register a listener to a specific component, you already know which component it is, so you can register a listener doing the right thing for exactly that component.

In this case, when the costs are stored in an array, there should also be a corresponding array used for building the menu items, which allows constructing items and corresponding listeners.

E.g.

```
static String[] dorms  = { "Allen Hall", "Pike Hall", "Farthing Hall" };
static int[] dormCosts = {           10,          20,              40 };
static String[] meals  = { "7 / weak", "14 / week", "unlimited" };
static int[] mealCosts = {          5,           8,          15 };
JTextField totalField = new JTextField();
int dormCost = dormCosts[0];
int mealCost = mealCosts[0];

void updateTotalCosts() {
    int totalCost = dormCost + mealCost; // really plus not multiply?
    totalField.setText("$" + totalCost);
}

JMenuBar buildMenu() {
    final JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = mb.add(new JMenu("Meals"));
    for(int ix = 0; ix < meals.length; ix++) {
        int currMealCosts = mealCosts[ix];
        menu.add(meals[ix]).addActionListener(ev -> {
            mealCost = currMealCosts;
            updateTotalCosts();
        });
    }
    menu = mb.add(new JMenu("Dorms"));
    for(int ix = 0; ix < dorms.length; ix++) {
        int currDormCosts = dormCosts[ix];
        menu.add(dorms[ix]).addActionListener(ev -> {
            dormCost = currDormCosts;
            updateTotalCosts();
        });
    }
    return mb;
}
```

In each loop iteration we do already know which item we’re creating and which costs are associated with it, so we register a listener using exactly those costs.

If you can’t use lambda expressions, the pre-Java 8 variant of the construction method would look like

```
JMenuBar buildMenu() {
    final JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = mb.add(new JMenu("Meals"));
    for(int ix = 0; ix < meals.length; ix++) {
        final int currMealCosts = mealCosts[ix];
        menu.add(meals[ix]).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                mealCost = currMealCosts;
                updateTotalCosts();
            }
        });
    }
    menu = mb.add(new JMenu("Dorms"));
    for(int ix = 0; ix < dorms.length; ix++) {
        final int currDormCosts = dormCosts[ix];
        menu.add(dorms[ix]).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                dormCost = currDormCosts;
                updateTotalCosts();
            }
        });
    }
    return mb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this approach won't work. You cannot access your UI components from inside the ActionListener.

You might want to try to add an anonymous listener to your JMenuItems that updates attributes of you class to perform the calculation.

**Edit**: Check Holger's answer for a nice solution :)

This way you can access the outer components or better delegate this to a model class.
See here: https://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/java-8-lambda-listener-example

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that there is no relationship between `.getComponentCount()`, the clicked menu, nor the array index.

Comment: You are right, I should have left the code snipped out, it problably was more confusing than helping.